# AgoraRTCError CAN_NOT_GET_GATEWAY_SERVER

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I am having issue joining a channel. I am making us of *agora-web-sdk-ng*.

Below is my code to join a channel:

```
  async startVideoStream() {

    this.rtc.client = AgoraRTC.createClient({ mode: "live", codec: "h264", role: 'host' });

    const uid = await this.rtc.client.join(this.options.appId, this.options.channel, this.options.token || null);

    this.rtc.localAudioTrack = await AgoraRTC.createMicrophoneAudioTrack();
    this.rtc.localVideoTrack = await AgoraRTC.createCameraVideoTrack();
    this.rtc.localVideoTrack.play('streamVideo')
    await this.rtc.client.publish([this.rtc.localAudioTrack, this.rtc.localVideoTrack]);

  }
```

But for unknown reasons, I keep on getting this error:

> core.js:4197 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): AgoraRTCError CAN_NOT_GET_GATEWAY_SERVER: invalid token, authorized failed data: {"retry":false}
> at resolvePromise

Answer (score 0):

I think the token needs to be the first param for that `join` call:

```
const uid = await this.rtc.client.join(this.options.token || null, this.options.channel, this.options.appId);
```

https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.client.html#agorartc.client.html#join

Comment: i am making use of Agora web sdk ng. according to there documentation its not.

https://agoraio-community.github.io/AgoraWebSDK-NG/docs/en/basic_call

Comment: Ah, my mistake, do you need to pass a 4th param as null? My guess is that the token is not setup correctly based on the error response though.

Comment: something is wrong, but i dont know what is causing it. their documentation doesn't cater to such errors. the fourth param is optional